# I have a method that is unboxing primitive type to object .I would like to make it a generic method for performance and make it look more cleaner

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, datareader, boxing

I have a method that is unboxing primitive type to object .I would like to make it a generic method for performance and make it look more cleaner.

```
public object Getkey( IDataReader reader, Type fieldType)
{

if (fieldtype==typeof(Int64))
{
return reader.GetInt64(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType== typeof(Int16))
{
return reader.GetInt16(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType== typeof(float))
{
return reader.Getfloat(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType==typeof(byte))
{
return reader.Getbyte(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType== typeof(double))
{
return reader.Getdouble(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType== typeof(decimal))
{
return reader.Getdecimal(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
if (fieldType==typeof(DateTime))
{
return reader.GetDateTime(_keyFieldReaderIndex)
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question, specifically? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to remove the if else statement. I know strategy pattern will remove it however I want to avoid typecasting/unboxing

Comment: Your code won't compile (if statements require parentheses).  Consider using a switch instead of a cascading series of if-s

Comment: @Flydog57 You can't switch on a `Type`

Comment: Returning `object` is unlikely to be what you want. If you need a specific type e.g. to assign to a property, just call the relevant `IDataReader` method directly.

Comment: What is the purpose of all this code if your return an object?

Comment: @SudiptoSarkar So you want to have a method `public T Getkey<T>(IDataReader reader)`?

Comment: Yes ,that's the exact requirement @canton7

Comment: @SudiptoSarkar that won't be possible using `fieldType`; that's only known at runtime, whereas generic arguments need to be provided at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Following your requirements of:

1. Method signature is `public T Getkey<T>(IDataReader reader)`
2. No boxing/unboxing

You can write it like this:

```
public T M<T>(IDataReader reader)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(long))
    {
        long result = reader.GetInt64(_keyFieldReaderIndex);
        return Unsafe.As<long, T>(ref result);
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(short))
    {
        short result = reader.GetInt16(_keyFieldReaderIndex);
        return Unsafe.As<short, T>(ref result);
    }
    // etc...
}
```

(You'll need the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) NuGet package if you're not using .NET Core.)

**However**, I'm not convinced this is a sensible thing to be doing. Presumably you've got some code which is doing:

```
bool result = GetKey<bool>(reader);
```

Why not just change this code to read:

```
bool result = reader.GetBoolean(_keyFieldReaderIndex);
```

Failing that, I'd prefer to write out a bunch of helper methods, like:

```
public bool GetBoolean(IDataReader reader) => reader.GetBoolean(_keyFieldReaderIndex);
```

That will be significantly shorter (one line per type, as opposed to 5 lines per type if you use the generic method above), avoids the `Unsafe` business, and is a bit nicer to use.